# how to do type-based (datacontext) selection of a XAML drawing?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using `HyerarchicalDataTemplate` that provide a proper template for a `TreeViewItem` based on the type of the `DataContext`.

I have a 2 levels tree view : Group -> Entity. Now, the entities can be of different types, and I would like to assign them an icon built from simple XAML forms in a `ResourceDictionary` file, depending on their type, and I didn't find a proper way to do it.

Here is a preview of my `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityTreeViewModel}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckSelected}" />
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Entity}" Content="???" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Entity.Name}" />
  </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The `ContentControl` is where I would like to put my XAML icon, but I am ready to use any other component that would do the job.

So basically : how to display there an icon build in XAML and that depends on the type of my entity, like
 Entity type A -> IconA
 Entity type B -> IconB

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Define different DataTemplates for different Entity types (with the Entity type use for a DataTemplate's `DataType` property) and bind the ContentControl's `Content` property to `Entity`. The DataTemplate should then be selected automatically (and be assigned to the ContentControl's `ContentTemplate` property).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Entity}" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityA}">
            <Image Source="iconA.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EntityB}">
            <Image Source="iconB.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

The classes `EntityA` and `EntityB` derives from the same `Entity` base class or implement the same interface and are defined in the namespace `WpfApplication1`.